# How do I stop a Regular Expression when I reach a certain character in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url, url-rewriting

I have a string, `/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2?parameter1=parameter2`. This is just the `REQUEST_URI` I am using for my website.

I want to split this string into separate array elements using PHP, and the following code works fine for this action: `preg_split('[/]', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`.

This works almost perfectly, providing me with an excellent array output, until I add get variables. With these, the last array element includes the get variables too.

My question is, is there a way to stop processing as soon as a question mark (?) is reached?

I want to cut it from the question mark, and only show items before the question mark. This (hopefully) will mean that this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller
    [1] => method
    [2] => parameter1
    [3] => parameter2?parameter1=parameter2
)
```

Will become this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller
    [1] => method
    [2] => parameter1
    [3] => parameter2
)
```

The problem is, I want this all in the regular expression. I don't really care if there is another way (I know there is), I just want to know if there is a way to do this in the regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace ?(.*) using:

```
preg_split('[/]', 
preg_replace("/\?(.*)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 
NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode before split

```
$vars = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$array = preg_split('[/]', $vars[0], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**UPDATE**

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

> If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose
>   faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like [explode()](http://php.net/explode) or [str_split](http://php.net/str_split)().

In your case you can use **str_split** and save some time.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my system with `strpos` and `substr` before using regex:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri = ($pos = strpos($uri, '?')) ? substr($uri, 0, $pos) : $uri;
```